# Use Concat and Trim with Ruby's Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have the following query:

```
select distinct db
from aliasnames
where concat(trim(group), ' ', trim(subgrp)) like 'My Client'
```

How can I do this with Ruby's Sequel?

Answer (score 2):

```
DB[:table].select(Sequel.join([:a,'b','c'],',')).sql
=> "SELECT CONCAT(`a`, ',', 'b', ',', 'c') FROM `table`"

DB[:table].select(Sequel.join([:a,'b','c'])).sql
=> "SELECT CONCAT(`a`, 'b', 'c') FROM `table`"

DB[:table].select(Sequel.trim(:a)).sql
=> "SELECT trim(`a`) FROM `table`"

DB[:table].select { concat(a,b,c) }.sql
=> "SELECT concat(`a`, `b`, `c`) FROM `table`"

DB[:table].select { concat(trim(a),b,c) }.sql
=> "SELECT concat(trim(`a`), `b`, `c`) FROM `table`"
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of SQL DB are you using? MySQL has both [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), so you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT db FROM aliasnames WHERE CONCAT(TRIM(group), ' ', TRIM(subgrp)) LIKE 'My Client'
```

The same is true for PostgreSQL -- here's a link to [string functions in their documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html).

UPDATE: 
I'm not very familiar with that Sequel toolkit, but it looks like you can just wrap your query like so:

```
results = DB.fetch("SELECT DISTINCT db FROM aliasnames WHERE CONCAT(TRIM(group), ' ', TRIM(subgrp)) LIKE 'My Client'")
```

Comment: I believe the question is about the Ruby Sequel library: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/

Comment: I see that now and have updated my answer accordingly :)

Comment: I have tried DB.fetch, but unfortunately that doesn't return the results in a key value pair like sequel normally does.

Comment: I'm seeing that DB.fetch should return an array of hashes, where each entry corresponds to a row and is keyed by column. What are your results like?

Comment: It is just joined the column name and field as one string it seems. If I just select distinct db from blah. And then do a db.each do.... and put each row, it shows like dbASDFSD dbASEIEHE dbAEHOIE